# php if username is role

Tags: php, users, username

I know you can easily display custom content if a certain logged in user is a certain role using

```
<?php if ( current_user_can('contributor') ) : ?>
    media files loop
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, I want to do the same thing, but for a specific username, not the logged in user.

I have user profiles in my wordpress website, some of them are artists, and If the profile being viewed is an artist I want to display their uploaded media. (and nothing to be returned if that profile being viewed is another role.)

I have the variable to get the currently viewed profiles username, I just need the if statement.

Something like:

media files loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Haugen,

You need to check user role who have 'artist' role and then you need to act on some video loop stuff.

Here's the solution:

```
$user = get_user_by('login', $username );

if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        foreach ( $user->roles as $role ){             
           if($role == 'artist')
              media files loop
        }
}
```

get_user_by() is return user data of passed 'username'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to check the "username"? if so:

```
<?php 
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user = $user->user_login; ?>

<?php if($user == "John"): ?>
 media files loop
<?php endiif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no. I'm trying to see if a certain username is a specific role. It is NOT the user who is logged in. the username associated with a profile.

I guess it would be something like:

`global $userpro;
$other_username = get_query_var('up_username');``<?php if($other_username == "vendor"): ?>
 media files loop
<?php endiif; ?>`

by vendor I mean the user role